# Python regex to match string excluding word

Tags: python, regex

I have an issue on building a regex and I've searched for 2 days all around Google, Stack Overflow and other documentations...

I have the following lines:

```
2015-07-08 12:49:07.183852|INFO    |VirtualServerBase|  3| client disconnected 'Ròem'(id:6336) reason 'invokerid=20 invokername=Alphonse invokeruid=loremipsum2= reasonmsg=test'
2015-07-08 11:59:23.178055|INFO    |VirtualServerBase|  3| client disconnected 'Trakiyen'(id:20460) reason 'invokerid=0 invokername=server reasonmsg=idle time exceeded'
2015-07-08 12:40:50.591450|INFO    |VirtualServerBase|  3| client disconnected 'kalash'(id:20464) reason 'invokerid=136 invokername=Charles invokeruid=loremipsum= reasonmsg=Aller, Bisous! bantime=0
2015-07-08 00:23:03.235312|INFO    |VirtualServerBase|  3| client disconnected 'Brigata FTW'(id:20451) reason 'invokerid=103 invokername=Bob invokeruid=loremipsum3= reasonmsg=En vous souhaitant une bonne soirée <3 bantime=28800'
```

I want to match only the first line, following those conditions:

1. No line with `invokername=server`
2. No line with `bantime`

In that case the result should only match the first line with the following regex:

```
.*2015-07-08.*client disconnected.*invokername=[^server].*[^bantime=].*
```

I only write here one regex but I've tried many and many differents things (with `?!`, etc). I've read a lot topics about excluding on Stack Overflow but could not find a solution. I hope someone will help me.

Comment: `[^server]` is not doing what you think it does. It matches everything that is not "s", "e", "r" and "v", and not everything that's not the word "server" (the same thing holds for `[^bantime=]`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get your line with

```
(?m)^(?!.*\b(?:invokername=server|bantime)\b).*2015-07-08.*client disconnected.*invokername=.*$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xB4vS7/1)

**EXPLANATION**:

- `(?m)` - A multiline flag so that `^` and `$` could match at the start and end of the sentence.
- `^` - Start of line anchor
- `(?!.*\b(?:invokername=server|bantime)\b)` - A negative look-ahead that is making sure there is no whole words `invokername=server` or `bantime` further on the line
- `.*2015-07-08.*client disconnected.*invokername=.*` - substring containing `2015-07-08`, `client disconnected`, `invokername=` and anything can be in-between those substrings (but a linebreak).
- `$` - End of line

Alternatively, you can just match *any line that has no disallowed substrings:

```
(?m)^(?!.*\b(?:invokername=server|bantime)\b).*$
```

This is a much better alternative if it does not "overmatch" for you.

Comment: I've read with interest your solution, thank you. I'm not very familiar with regex optimization :)

Comment: There is no magic here, the rule is only one: complexity should be linear. Try to avoid alternation if parts of it may match the same text. If you do not need a tempered greedy token (used by Kasra), do not use it (it only helps when parsing long logs with optional parts). If using look-aheads, anchor them. I suggest reading [rexegg.com](http://www.rexegg.com) to get an advanced feel of regex and regex optimization.

Answer (score 3):

Alongside the @llogiq's answer which explained the difference between *negated character class* and *negative look-ahead*,you can also use only following regex using [negative look ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) :

```
^((?!bantime|(?:invokername=server)).)*$
```

See demo https://regex101.com/r/hI5dR0/1

```
>>> re.search(r'^((?!bantime|(invokername=server)).)*$',s,re.M).group()
"015-07-08 12:49:07.183852|INFO    |VirtualServerBase|  3| client disconnected 'R\xc3\xb2em'(id:6336) reason 'invokerid=20 invokername=Alphonse invokeruid=loremipsum2= reasonmsg=test'"
```

Comment: Tempered greedy token is too inefficient in comparison with a simple anchored negative lookahead with alternations used before `.*`. Compare the number of steps your regex takes and my "equivalent" (`(?m)^(?!.*\b(?:invokername=server|bantime)\b).*$`).

Comment: @stribizhev Yep you are right! I didn't see you solution!

Comment: Anyway, it's valid :)

Answer (score 2):

You seem to confuse `[^...]` with `(?!...)`. The former is a negated character class group, while the latter is a negative lookahead.

If we now also keep in mind that negative lookahead is applied at the current position, we need:

```
.*?2015-07-08.*?client disconnected.*?(invokername=(?!server))((?!.*?bantime=).*)
```

Edit: Credit where credit is due: @stribizhev's solution is better than mine:

```
(?m)^(?!.*\b(?:invokername=server|bantime)\b).*$
```

Comment: I am not sure but it seems [it matches 3 lines](https://regex101.com/r/gX9jJ6/1), not as expected.

Comment: This does not process the `bantime` part correctly, as it will first jump as far as possible before trying to test for `bantime`. Try something like `.*2015-07-08.*client disconnected.*invokername=(?!server)(?!.*bantime=).*` or put the lookahead at start even.

Comment: Ok i got it with the difference between [ ] and ( ). However it still not returning the correct thing. I don't have the line with "server" but still lines with "bantime="

Comment: Ok it works with Andris modification, adding .* before bantime ! Thank you very much everybody !!!

Comment: @Gladrat: [2500 steps to complete](https://regex101.com/r/sZ3lJ9/1) vs. mine that [takes 981 steps to complete](https://regex101.com/r/sZ3lJ9/2) (or [597 steps if you use simplified regex](https://regex101.com/r/sZ3lJ9/3). This solution will reach [catastrophic backtracking](https://regex101.com/r/sZ3lJ9/4) quickly with larger logs (see [mine with the same text](https://regex101.com/r/sZ3lJ9/5)).